# Как создать заголовочный файл Js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Возник следующий вопрос, который не удалось нагуглить
Имеются 2 проекта. Один на c++(с использованием chromium) второй на js.
В проекте с с++ есть файлы js которые выполняются в хроме и являются апи для второго проекта. Пример файла

```
function TestFunction(){}

/**
* @param {number} par1 параметр1
* @param {number} par2 параметр2
* */
TestFunction.prototype.make = function(par1,par2) {
    console.log('необходимые действия');       
}
```

Необходим инструмент, что бы автоматически парсился этот файл и создавал файл с описанием, но без реализации

```
function TestFunction(){}

/**
* @param {number} par1 параметр1
* @param {number} par2 параметр2
* */
TestFunction.prototype.make = function(par1,par2) {}
```

Что бы это копировалось в другой проект и можно было использовать IntelliSense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

То, что вам нужно, называется парсер языка JavaScript. Уверен, есть тысячи их, и на любых языках. Как вариант, этот https://esprima.org/, на на самом себе (JavaScript).